# WordPress backend does not show all post

Tags: wordpress, backend, custom-post-type, posts

I have created a custom post type. Sometime during the last few days, posts are no longer visible in the list, however it still shows the total number of posts.

[image]

See here it shows all post(18), published post (13), but it only shows one post in list.

Comment: Have you installed any new plugins? Do you have any errors if you set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in your `wp-config.php`?

Comment: Show code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you repair database tables and check below solution it can be REGEX issue :

```
translations.php
line 726
Change this: $pattern = '/LIMIT\s*(\d+)((\s*,?\s*)(\d+)*)(;{0,1})$/is';
to this: $pattern = '/LIMIT\s*(\d+)((\s*,?\s*)(\d+)*);{0,1}$/is';
```

You can see it on : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51134/dashboard-says-no-posts-found-even-though-there-are-some-posts

Comment: where should I get this file?

Comment: Can you disable plugin one by one and check which plugin cause the issue , and please enable debug mode on.

Comment: ok let me try this way. Actually all this things happen because of wordpress update

Comment: Yes try this way and change the theme after that twik does not work and check

Comment: still not getting any solution. Pleease help

Comment: are you using plugin OR using function.php code to create CPT

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203184/discussion-between-neal-developer-and-arti-rana).